# Access coastal outlines (e.g. from Basemap, or somewhere else) without installing Basemap

Tags: python, blender, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to have polygons or vertices of coastlines on the Earth to manipulate in Blender (and in Python stand-alone), but I would like to avoid installing into each of the multiple Pythons on my computer. Basically it looks a bit tricky to do once, much less four times.

All I want is points along coastline contours, say at 1 or even 10 kilometer (1000m or 10000m)  resolution. I'm assuming they would be in latitude/longitude, and in that case I would just convert to x, y, z in space myself.

I've downloaded Basemap - is there any way I can access the contours directly in the `data` folder?

An alternate data source would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution which does not involve Basemaps or the like, thanks to the answer in GIS.stackexchange [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/164930/60078)

I am reposting some of the info here:

*The answer by @artwork21 is the accepted answer. I am just adding some supplementary information that others may find useful.*

*I downloaded some coastline data from the link provided in the answer. In this example, I used physical vector data from [here](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-physical-vectors/). Then reading about [pyshp](https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/) I just copy/pasted the script [shapefile.py](http://pyshp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shapefile.py) and then did the following:*

```
coast = Reader("ne_50m_coastline")     # defined in shapefile.py

plt.figure()

for shape in coast.shapes()[:20]:   # first 20 shapes out of 1428 total

    x, y = zip(*shape.points)

    plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlim(110, 180)
plt.ylim(-40, 20)

plt.savefig("Australia Australia Australia Australia we love ya' Amen") 
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_f_p0CgPeyA&feature=youtu.be&t=121

plt.show()
```

[image: Australia!]